# Ubuntu 22.04 ACPI BIOS error

Tags: boot, 22.04, bios, acpi, usb-installation

I have a problem with installing Ubuntu via a USB flash drive. When I tried to run the installation, I got this error.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: There's some missing detail here. Can you maybe take a wider photo as a lot of text is off screen.